# Parse error in Artisan after create cron job

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, laravel-artisan

I got this error in error_log after create cron job on cpanel.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING
>   or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/kardenoc/Smartflyer/artisan on line 33

this is the line mentioned:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

I'm using php 7.2(choose php 7.2 on cpanel) and laravel 6.
whole process is working expect this cron job.

Comment: What php version do you get when you execute `php -v` in your terminal. It is possible that this is not the same as the webserver version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `php` command in the cPanel is using an older version.

The quick solution for you is to use the `php7.2` command. E.g. put this in the cron job:

```
php7.2 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Cpanel version could be different from laravel version please check **composer.json** for this line

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9"
```